# Escape value in echo statement in Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra

So i've been working on adding a few aliases to the .bash_profile to make it easier to set up composer PHP/Composer projects on my Mac.I've gotten very close to completing this but i'm having an issue. I'm trying to output a string to a file i'm creating but the single quotes keep getting removed.

The alias i'm setting up is as follows:

```
alias sp='touch index.php; echo "<?php  \n\n  require_once __DIR__ . $ '/vendor/autoload.php' ?>;" >> index.php; open/Applications/TextWrangler.app index.php;'
```

The output i'm getting in the php file is:

```
<?php  \n\n require_once __DIR__ . $ /vendor/autoload.php \n\n ?>
```

I've tried escaping using \e and $'string'

But have had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: When doing anything nontrivial, use functions instead of aliases and `printf` instead of `echo`.

Long answer: the immediate problem is that quotes don't nest. You're trying to use single-quotes around an alias that contains single-quotes, and that won't work. The shell is parsing your command as containing the single-quoted segment `'touch index.php; echo "<?php  \n\n  require_once __DIR__ . $ '`, followed by the unquoted segment `/vendor/autoload.php`, followed by the single-quoted segment `' ?>;" >> index.php; open/Applications/TextWrangler.app index.php;'` -- it removes the quotes, mashes them together, and assigns the result as the alias.

There are ways to fix this, but they're ugly. Things like `alias sp='touch ... $ '"'"'/vendor/...` -- here, the first single-quote ends the single-quoted segment, then there's a double-quoted segment containing a single-quote, then the beginning of another single-quoted segment. Bleh.

Really, when defining an alias gets this complicated, you're better off switching to a function. Among other things they don't need to be quoted, so this whole problem is moot:

```
sp() {
    touch index.php
    echo "<?php  \n\n  require_once __DIR__ . $ '/vendor/autoload.php' ?>;" >> index.php
    open/Applications/TextWrangler.app index.php
}
```

But as long as I'm making suggestions, I'd make a couple of other changes. First, the `touch` command isn't doing anything that the redirect isn't going to do anyway, so I'd leave it out. Second, using `\n` with `echo` is unpredictable; some versions of `echo` convert it to newlines, some don't. It's actually changed between different versions of OS X. You're much better off using `printf` for this, although it's more complicated to use properly. The first argument to `printf` is a format string that's used to control how the rest of the arguments are printed. The other big difference from `echo` is that it doesn't automatically add a newline to the end, so you have to do that yourself. I'm assuming you want to put this into the index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . $ '/vendor/autoload.php'

?>
```

There are several ways to do this with `printf`. Probably the simplest would be to make each line an argument, and use the format string to put a newline after each one:

```
printf '%s\n' "<?php" "" "require_once __DIR__ . \$ '/vendor/autoload.php'" "" "?>"
```

But In this case I'd use `cat` with a here-document. You can do that inside a function (unlike an alias):

```
sp() {
    cat <<"EOF" >>index.html
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . $ '/vendor/autoload.php'

?>
EOF
    open/Applications/TextWrangler.app index.php
}
```

If you want cleaner indentation, you can also use `<<-"EOF"`, and then indent the here-doc content with tabs (*not* spaces).

Comment: Great answer! Very much appreciate all of the information.